# ST_Within not working

Tags: postgis

I made an insert into a table in this format.

```
insert into stg_place.stg_geo (data) values
(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((101.687764 3.134461,101.687582 3.131033,101.690898 3.132327,101.687764 3.134461)))',
                 4326));
```

This is a triangle and each of these points is in LONG LAT format.

Now, I was trying to confirm whether the polygon is correct. So , i did a test to find this long/lat in the polygon - 101.687764/3.134461 using the below query.

It didn't return any records. What is wrong in this ?

```
select * from stg_place.stg_geo where 
ST_Within(ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT('||101.687764||' '||3.134461||')'),data);
```

Answer (score 5):

The point you are using is not within the polygon, it is on its boundary. The [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Contains.html) on `ST_Contains` mention this subtlety while the doc on `ST_Within` doesn't...
To solve this, you can use [`ST_Covers`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Covers.html) instead

```
select st_covers(poly, pt), st_contains(poly, pt) 
from (
      select (ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((101.687764 3.134461,101.687582 3.131033,101.690898 3.132327,101.687764 3.134461)))',4326)) poly,
              ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(101.687764 3.134461)') pt
     ) src;

 st_covers | st_contains
-----------+-------------
 t         | f
```